# What is this bash script trying to do with mysql?

Tags: mysql, bash

The person who wrote the follow bash script has left and I need to figure out the meaning of the follow bash script he wrote. This script is executed in a docker container before running some test cases which requires a running mysql instance.

I guess it is about starting a mysql server, but I am not exactly sure about the exact meaning of each statement in this script.

```
echo -n "Loading [+"
( echo "SHOW TABLES;" | mysql mysql 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null ) || \
    run-mysqld 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null &

while ! ( echo "SHOW TABLES;" | mysql mysql 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null ) ; 
do
    echo -n +
    sleep 1
done
echo "] Done."
```

I had to figure out this because our bitbucket pipeline recently gets stuck and timeout when running this script (previously it was fine). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the repository this came from have a script called `run-mysqld`? I’m not great at bash, but it seems like this script is running a SHOW TABLES query against MySQL, and if that doesn’t output anything it runs the `run-mysqld` script in the background (hence the &), then keeps running the SHOW TABLES query against MySQL in a loop once a second until it actually returns something.

Comment: Per codeforester’s point, if the run-mysqld command doesn’t actually work and make it so that a SHOW TABLES query succeeds, this process will run infinitely. Since run-mysqld is being executed in the background, if it errors, it’ll do it silently.

Comment: Note that in most circumstances, questions of this type ("please explain this code") are considered too broad to be allowable here, unless narrowed to ask only a very narrow and specific question; see [How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta].

Comment: Charles Duffy, sorry. Will take note moving forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sequence attempts to run `SHOW TABLES` through mysql, ignoring any output.  If mysql fails (because mysqld isn't running), it starts mysqld to run in background.

```
( echo "SHOW TABLES;" | mysql mysql 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null ) || \
    run-mysqld 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null &
```

The second part of the code just waits for mysqld to start up, which is signaled by the following code exiting 0:

```
( echo "SHOW TABLES;" | mysql mysql 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null )
```

If mysqld doesn't come up with a single attempt, the second part of the code would run forever.  Looks like that's what happened.

The simplest way to make this code free from hanging is to put a limit on how long we sleep:

```
max_sleep=15
sleep=0
while ! ( echo "SHOW TABLES;" | mysql mysql 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null ) ; 
do
    echo -n +
    sleep 1
    ((sleep++ > max_sleep)) && { echo "Failed to start mysqld] Error."; exit 1; }
done
echo "] Done."
exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks codeforester. It does look very much like the cause of the problem. I tried setting up a container using the image used by my bitbucket pipeline on my local computer and this piece of script runs and finishes in 10 seconds. But when run on bitbucket pipeline, it just stuck forever until timeout. Do you have any suggestion on the reason? Thanks in advance